# eureka-js-client Why I cant use the same hostname for two service instances?

Tags: node.js, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am deploying two instances for the same service and the two are running on the same machine at different ports. Since it's a Nodejs application so i use eureka-js-client for regitering. My client config yml file are as follows:

```
eureka:
  heartbeatInterval: 30000
  registryFetchInterval: 30000
  host: 'username:passwor@ipAdrress'
  port: 8000
  servicePath: '/eureka/apps/'
  preferIpAddress: true

instance:
  app: 'nodejs-service'
  hostName: 'localhost'
  ipAddr: 'localhost'
  statusPageUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
  port:
    '$': 3000
    '@enabled': 'true'

  vipAddress: 'nodejs-service'
  dataCenterInfo:
    '@class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo'
    name: 'MyOwn'
```

And for the other instance, I simply change the port to 4000. When I register 3000 and 4000, it only shows 4000 instance on the eureka page. That's to say, only one instance is registered.While after i change one of the hostName value to something else, it works fine - two are registered. However, I need the hostNames be the same, because they are deployed on the same machine. For java, the same hostName is Ok, I am wondering is this problem caused by my yaml config file. Ask for help, thank you!

Comment: That's just how eureka was built. It uses hostnames or ip addresses as unique

Comment: I am sorry to give u feedback so late. I solved this problem by add instance-id property in the yml file of this nodejs application.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add instance-id property in the yml file like this:

```
instance:
  app: 'nodejs-service'
  instanceId: 'node1'
```